# How to get click event of device menu app list in android

Tags: android

I'm doing android application which integrates Service listeners.if I click any app in the main menu app list, this my own application should get the click event.I don't know is this possible in android?(ex)If I click facebook app in the list,my own app(with broadcast or any listeners) should get that package name of that clicked app.How could I do that?

Code:

...

public class MyService extends Service
 {

```
public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
            .getRunningTasks(1);
    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
    String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();

    Toast.makeText(this, activityOnTop, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
enter code here
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

But it shows only for this app package name. If I'm out of this app, & click some other app, it will not fetching up its package name.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to check the list of active services:

Loop through the running services repeatedly to detect the new additions in the list.

To get the active services,

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```